# Bootstrap xs ordering vs md ordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am busy with a website for a client. Everything is going good so far until it comes to Mobile/tablet design. Here is an example

This is the MD version.

```
-----------------  ------------------
| Left Content  |  |  Right Content | <-- Float: Right and Margin-right -15
-----------------  ------------------
```

this is the XS version now

```
------------------
| left Content  |
--------------------
  | Right   Content| 
  ------------------
```

the XS Version that i want

```
-----------------
| left Content  |
-----------------
| right Content |
-----------------
```

the only way i can fix this is to disable float right for the "right content" so it will stack precisely under each other. But then i do not have spacing and correct order if its on .MD mode.

I tried the following:

Offset-xs-*
Pull left
Pull right
push left
push right

is there anyone that can help me out my misery?

I uploaded the website at

http://www.clbmedia.nl

Comment: Do you have some code? I think it has to do with adding the `float: right` and the `margin-right: -15px` on a `col-*` class. You shouldn't change Bootstraps `.container`, `.row`, or `.col-*` classes. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: '<div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 m1"> <-- m1 is margin
          <div class="col-md-6 whitebox1"> 
              Content left
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 whitebox4 col-xs-12 "> 
"Whitebox4 has the property float right"
content right
</div>'

What i am trying to achieve is that if i dont float and use margin, it stack right next to each other. I have no spacing at all. I know i should not change the properties of bootstrap but as far i know i am changing only the divs. Again i could be wrong obviously

Comment: Sorry i am new in stack overflow and i see that the code snippet is a mess!!

Comment: just to clear things up i uploaded the site at : www.clbmedia.nl ! sorry for my lack of response. I have been very busy lately with figuring out what to do with this mess i created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically floating the elements, try inserting the helper class "clearfix" to the parent div.

```
<div class="row clearfix">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the smallest possible column layout that shows the columns next to each other on `md` and stacks them on `xs` and `sm`.

Quite likely this doesn't completely answer the question as your comments indicate you need some spacing. The text inside the boxes currently has 15px on every side. Do you perhaps mean space between the background colors?

```css
.pink {
  background-color: #f99;
}

.green {
  background-color: #9f9;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 pink">Left Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 green">Right Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```